# Strange ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, graph, user-input

I've ran in to a wierd error that I think shouldn't be happening, I first tested the code by hard coding everything in the driver, then I made a menu, and that's where it's happening. This is the error for one of the methods.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
   at graph.GraphMatrix.dfs(GraphMatrix.java:92)
   at graph.Driver.main(Driver.java:61)
```

This is a Depth first search method for Graph

```
public ArrayList<String> dfs(String x)
{
    ArrayList<String> visited = new ArrayList<String>();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    stack.push(x); 

    while(!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        visited.add(x);

        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
        {
 line92 --> if(matrix[getIndex(x)][i] && !visited.contains(vertices[i]))
            {
                stack.push(vertices[i]);
            }
        } 
        x = stack.pop();
    }
    return visited;
}
```

I believe it has to do with getIndex method but then I don't think so because if I hard code it in the driver like `m.dfs("B");` everything works perfectly

```
 public int getIndex(String x)
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
        if(x.equals(vertices[i]))
            return i;
    return -1;
 }
```

But when I do it like this to let the user pick from a menu and enter the letter it gives me the arryoutofbound....same thing for my other menu options, hard coding works but user entering is giving arryoutofbound. Any ideas why? Thanks.

```
 case 3:
    System.out.println("Do Depth-first-search for: ");
    key = kb.nextLine();
    kb.next();

line61->System.out.println(m.dfs(key));
    break;
```

Comment: What do you mean when you hard code it ? it will be easier if you show an example (with user input and output). And more importantly it will be easier for you to solve it if you debug it step by step

Comment: Did you check the value of key? it could have a trailing \n causing your string comparison to fail in getIndex()

Comment: @Sasikanth your totally right, nothings getting stored in key, but why is that it should be working, im not new to programming whats going on?

Comment: How are you reading user input? what is  "kb" in kb.nextLine()?

Comment: kb is the scanner btw, and I got it, so apparently it should be     key = kb.next(); I dont get it shouldnt nextLine() work tho?